# OTRS REST - Invoker is not sending POST data

Tags: perl, web-services, rest, otrs

I have configured OTRS 4.0.2 (cannot update it because it is used on production environment) with an REST invoker in a Perl module (GenericInterface - OTRS as requestor), calling a test web service `http://www.example.com/log/index.php` page to debug the OTRS request.

I activated the debug feature and queried the database:

```sql
SELECT
  gidec.id,
  gidec.gi_debugger_entry_id,
  gidec.subject,
  CONCAT(gidec.content),
  gidec.create_time
FROM     gi_debugger_entry_content gidec
WHERE    gidec.gi_debugger_entry_id = 182
ORDER BY gidec.id DESC
```

It returns the following items:

```
Communication sequence started
Incoming data before mapping
JSON data received from remote system
Outgoing data before mapping
Remaining outgoing data to be sent
URI after interpolating Query params from outgoing data
URI after interpolating URI params from outgoing data
```

My issue is with: *Remaining outgoing data to be sent*

It contains:

```perl
$VAR1 = {
  'Priority' => 'Priority:5 very high',
  'TestPrepareRequestRCS' => 'TestPrepareRequest009',
  'TicketID' => '5'
};
```

But on the web service (PHP language) that is called through POST, I don't receive data (I am using function to serialize superglobals `$_POST` and `$_GET`):

Request using `GET` by the invoker to the web service ( `/log/index.php` ):

```
GET = a:4:   {s:8:"TicketID";s:1:"5";s:7:"invoker";s:6:"zwsync";s:8:"Priority";s:20:"Priority:5 very high";s:21:"TestPrepareRequestRCS";s:21:"TestPrepareRequest009";}
POST = a:0:{}
```

Request using `POST` by the Invoker to the Web Service ( `/log/index.php` ):

```
GET = a:4:{s:8:"TicketID";s:1:"5";s:7:"invoker";s:6:"zwsync";}
POST = a:0:{}
```

To use `POST` on OTRS web service, do I have to configure anything else?

Comment: Tagged `perl`. Don't see much `perl`.

Comment: The REST invoker is a Perl module in OTRS. I did not attach the whole file, but if needed I can add it.